# Any way to get the "Open With..." list via AppleScript?

Tags: finder, applescript

I want to create an AppleScript that gets the Finder selection and displays a list of applications that are capable of opening it.

In other words, is there any way to get the list of apps that appears when you use Finder's "Open With >" contextual submenu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use [AllApplications](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/AllApplications/AllApplications.html) in a shell script:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set p to POSIX path of (item 1 of (get selection) as text)
end tell
set l to do shell script "~/bin/AllApplications -path " & quoted form of p & " | sed 's/.*\\///g;s/\\.app$//g' | sort -f | uniq"
set answer to choose from list (paragraphs of l) without multiple selections allowed
if answer is false then return
set a to item 1 of answer
set p to path to application a
tell application "Finder" to open selection using p
```

You could also use System Events to get the applications from the Open With menu:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    set l to name of menu items of menu 1 of menu item "Open With" of menu 3 of menu bar 1
end tell
set text item delimiters to linefeed
set l2 to do shell script "grep -vx 'missing value' <<< " & quoted form of (l as text) & " | grep -vx Other… | sed -E 's/ \\([^)]*\\)$//g;s/ \\(default\\)$//g;s/\\.app$//g' | sort -f | uniq"
set answer to choose from list (paragraphs of l2) without multiple selections allowed
if answer is false then return
set a to item 1 of answer
set p to (path to application a)
tell application "Finder" to open selection using p
```

I didn't really test the scripts, but they're probably affected by [rdar://9406282: Finder scripting selection may refer to bogus value not correlated with UI](http://www.openradar.me/9406282).

Related questions at Super User:

- [Access Finder's "Open With" menu from the commandline (for tab completion)](https://superuser.com/questions/316490/access-finders-open-with-menu-from-the-commandline-for-tab-completion)
- [Is it possible to query the launch services database for applications that will open an arbitrary file or UTI type?](https://superuser.com/questions/323599/is-it-possible-to-query-the-launch-services-database-for-applications-that-will?lq=1)

Comment: Holy cow! Fantastic! They both work; the AllApplications method is much faster. Thank you!